# Help with PHP preg_replace() REGEX for MP3 URLs

Tags: php, mp3, anchor, href

Ive looked around quite a bit for a regex to help me find a anchor tag with an mp3 as the href. I would like first to get a regex which will locate this pattern so i can replace those links with a player and next i need to extract the link out of the href.

I hardly understand how to create or use a regex so any help to accomplish this will be useful.

Thanks,
Jesse

Comment: Are you looking for regex patter?

Comment: I have a good rewrite rule against such a hotlinkers :)

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you already got the links —e.g. [get_elements_by_tagname('a')](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.domdocument-get-elements-by-tagname.php)— all you need to do is:

```
if( substr($href, -4)=='.mp3' ){
    // Is an MP3 link
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick

```
~<a.*?href="(?P<url>.*?\.mp3(?:\?.*?)?)".*?>~is
```

however, it's hardly to be considered optimal.

Comment: what do you mean by its hardly optimal, is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

at first this didnt quite work for me. I made a couple of changes and now I got it. i needed to change the ~ to a / and i had to replace all the way to the closing anchor tag so heres what im using.

`/<a.*?href="(?P<url>.*?\.mp3(?:\?.*?)?)">.*?<\/a>/is`

Thanks for getting me in the right direction